# How to use Regex in DataSet.Tables.Select() in VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, select, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset that contains multiple values. I want to take those rows from that dataset from the datatable BLABLA that contains an "S" with the numbers from zero to six. Then I want to display those in a MessageBox.

My Regex is `S[0-6]`.

```
Dim answer As String = ""
Dim myregex As Regex = New Regex("S[0-6]")

Dim SearchRows() As DataRow = datasetB.Tables("BLABLA").Select("Data LIKE  '%myregex%'")

For k As Integer = 0 To SearchRows.Length - 1
    If answer = "" Then
        answer = SearchRows(k).Item("Data")
    Else
        answer = answer & vbNewLine & SearchRows(k).Item("Data")
    End If
Next

MsgBox(answer)
```

Unfortunately `SearchRows` is empty. I couldn't find the reason by debugging.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTable.Select` method does not support regex.  As [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select) states, it does allow you to pass it a `filterExpression` string as an argument, but just because it takes a filter expression doesn't mean that it support's regex expressions.  On the contrary, it's designed to mostly support the same kinds of expressions as the `WHERE` clause in T-SQL.  T-SQL's `LIKE` operator [does not support regex patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), and neither does `DataTable.Select`.  See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression) to learn the rules for the pattern expressions that are supported by the `DataTable.Select` method's `LIKE` operator.

The filter expressions supported by the `LIKE` operator are not as advanced as regex, so it's almost certainly impossible to construct a filter expression which is that specific.  If there is a way to filter to digits between 0 and 6, I am unaware of it and the documentation doesn't mention it.  So, if you really need to filter rows by regex, you can still do it, but you need to select *all* the rows and then filter them yourself:

```
Dim SearchRows() As DataRow = datasetB.Tables("BLABLA").Select().
    Where(Function(r) myregex.IsMatch(r.Item("Data").ToString())).
    ToArray()
```

Comment: How can I display the whole Row in the MessageBox? Till now it is only the column  named `Data`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that because I'm not sure what part of it you don't understand.  It seems like you already asked that and had it answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57205385/1359668).  So if that doesn't answer your question already, I'd need more clarification regarding what you really need and what exactly you don't understand.  Regardless, it's a different question, best asked as a new question rather than addressed in the comments here :)